# nextcord.py pillow module problem on Discloud

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library, nextcord

I'm using [discloud](https://discloudbot.com/dashboard) to host my discord bot 7/24, and i have to use Pillow module on python to create profile cards.

I fill requirements.txt file automatically by `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command on terminal, but when I upload it to  the server and try to use the command on discord, I don't get a response. Probably it returns an error on server but discloud doesn't display it.

my codes:

main.py file:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.components import SelectOption
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord.interactions import Interaction
from nextcord.ui import Button, View
from nextcord import Embed
from nextcord.utils import MISSING
from nextcord.utils import get
import asyncio
import datetime
import re
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageOps, ImageChops
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', intents=nextcord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command("help")
import requests
warnings = {}

def circle(pfp,size = (215,215)):
    
    pfp = pfp.resize(size, Image.LANCZOS).convert("RGBA")
    
    bigsize = (pfp.size[0] * 3, pfp.size[1] * 3)
    mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
    draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
    mask = mask.resize(pfp.size, Image.LANCZOS)
    mask = ImageChops.darker(mask, pfp.split()[-1])
    pfp.putalpha(mask)
    return pfp

@bot.command()
async def myprofile(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    name, nick, Id, status = str(member), member.display_name, str(member.id), str(member.status).upper()


    req = await bot.http.request(nextcord.http.Route("GET", "/users/{uid}", uid=member.id))
    banner_id = req["banner"]
    # If statement because the user may not have a banner
    if banner_id:
        banner_url = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/{member.id}/{banner_id}?size=1024"
        banner = im = Image.open(requests.get(banner_url, stream=True).raw)
    else:
        banner = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(696, 300),
                 color=member.accent_color)
    newsize = (696,300)
    banner = banner.resize(newsize)
    HEIGH_OF_THE_BLACK_AREA = 601

    with banner as im:        
        new_im = Image.new(im.mode, size = (im.size[0], im.size[1] + HEIGH_OF_THE_BLACK_AREA))

        new_im.putdata(im.getdata())

        banner = new_im
```

requirements.txt file:

```
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
anyio==3.6.2
asgiref==3.6.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
Django==4.2.1
ffmpeg==1.4
frozenlist==1.3.3
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==0.17.1
httpx==0.24.1
idna==3.4
image==1.5.33
multidict==6.0.4
nekos.py==1.1.0
nextcord==2.4.2
Pillow==9.5.0
plyer==2.1.0
pycparser==2.21
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pytube==15.0.0
pytube3==9.6.4
requests==2.29.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.5.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==1.26.15
Wavelink==2.1.0
winotify==1.1.0
yarl==1.8.2
youtube-dl==2021.12.17
youtube-search-python==1.4.2
```

i tried to find another module but there is no module like Pillow.

Edit:
I Changed the server to Huguitis Nodes, i can see the error now and i fixed it. the error is about fonts server. i called the fonts locally like: ' font = ImageFont.truetype("arial", 38)'

Comment: I would suggest using `print` statements to see where you went wrong.